# regular expression - excluding specific chars

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression matching a set without some chars.

For example, it matches `[ a-zA-Z]*` but excludes `i,o,q,I,O,Q`.

So: "A fat cat" matches, "Boy" doesn't.

Looks like it can be [`[ a-hj-npr-zA-HJ-NPR-Z]*`](http://regex101.com/r/mW0jM5/1).

Is there a simpler version for this?

Btw, I'm using it in `PostgreSQL`, but I think it should be a standard expression.

Comment: Googling this question would have given you a quicker answer. First hit on Google when searching with exactly your title: http://regexone.com/lesson/4

Comment: I don't know if PostgreSQL supports the following syntax: `[a-zA-Z&&[^ioqIOQ]]`. Could you have a try? Maybe `[a-zA-Z-[ioqIOQ]]` as well.

Comment: @skamazin I know how to exclude some chars, but don't know how to exclude them in a specific set, e.g. what if match in `[C-Zc-z]*` but not matching `i,o,q`?

Comment: @Deqing my fault for not reading the question thoroughly enough.

Comment: @Deqing Unfortunately, I don't know how to simplify that regex, but [I can make it more robust](http://regex101.com/r/lD2yI9/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead for this as [Postgresql support lookaheads](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html):

```
(?![ioqIOQ])[A-Za-z ]
```

To make it match complete line use:

```
^(?:(?![ioqIOQ])[A-Za-z ])+$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mW0jM5/3)

Comment: Looks like this only matches not starting with [ioqIOQ]

Comment: That's not correct. `(?![ioqIOQ])` is a lookahead, only affects next pattern which is `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: But you need to add a quantifier to have it apply to the whole string -- `(?![ioqIOQ]*$)[A-Za-z]*`

Comment: @tripleee I tried but looks like it is not working, can u double check? Thanks.

Comment: You're missing the space too

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Anubhava's answer, but extending to an entire string rather than just one character,

```
^(?=[^ioqIOQ]*$)[ A-Za-z]*$
```

The `(?=...)` is a positive lookahead -- the opposite of the negative lookahead in Anubhava's answer.  We are requiring all matches to also match the constraint `[^ioqIOQ]`.

You could also implement the repetition over the entire string with

```
^((?![ioqIOQ])[ A-Za-z])*$
```

but it seems a lot less efficient.  (I have not performed any timings, though.)

Comment: Ack contribution from @Anubhava.

Comment: Tried but not working :( I have some test cases in [here](http://regex101.com/r/mW0jM5/1).

Comment: That's more a feature of how the tester works.  With `/mg` flags added, you can make it match multiple times on a multi-line test string, but out of the box, it tries to match the entire multi-line string at once. See [this fork of your test](http://regex101.com/r/wQ5aD9/1).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Sorry I can't accept more than 1 answer!

Answer (score 1):

Don't need fancy lookaheads/behinds just use more, but smaller, character ranges.

You'll want something like `^[a-hj-npr-zA-HJ-NPR-Z ]*$`.

Added a space to match sentences

You can see test this on-line here at [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/0i0PXMNt_UdkT3yL)