# Regular Expression class set without specific char?

Tags: regex

I want to match non alphabet characters but excluding `"`, i.e., `\W` without `"`. How could I achieve that?

I have checked [regular expression - excluding specific chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407053/regular-expression-excluding-specific-chars). but how can I achieve this without looking ahead?

I want something like `[\W^"]`, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `[\W^"]` matches all non-word chars (including `"` and `^`), or `^`, or `"`. That means, the `^"` chars in your class are *redudant* and can be removed.

To exclude some chars from a shorthand character class (as in your case, `\W`), you may use a reverse character class in a negated character class, `[^\w]`, and add `"` there:

```
[^\w"]
```

This means: *any character but a word char or `"`*. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NCr68P/1).

Depending on the regex flavor, you may want to use [*Character class subtraction*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html). In Java, it would look like `[\W&&[^"]]` and in .NET, it would look like `[\W-["]]`.